# Apply cascaded style to element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, styles

I have a style tag that looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#Ribbon\.ListItem\.New\.NewListItem-Larges
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

I would like to know how to apply this style using jQUery.
Have tried this but it doesn't work

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">#Ribbon\.ListItem\.New\.NewListItem-Large{  display:none;}</style>');
```

Have applied to body as well to no avail.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you escaping the periods?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<style type='text/css'> #Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem-Larges{ display: none;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

It should work, but you'll need to remove those slashes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Had already tried this as well to no avail.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have `Larges` in your first bit of code and `Large` in the jquery.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I put the s on the end of Large to prevent the CSS from being used for my testing.

Comment: gotcha, did none of the other answers fix your problem?

Comment: No they didn't.  Tried everything.  No luck.  Tried putting in a delay on the page to wait for the entire page to load before executing, confirmed by alert that the routine was called.  Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.hide()` instead of appending a CSS to the head.

```
$(function(){
  $("#Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem-Larges").hide();
});
```

That is, if you are not creating this element dynamically.

Comment: Tried the hide method.  Didn't work either.  Thanks for the input

Comment: @Clem, "Didn't work" doesn't really help to clarify your problem

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is with proprietary code that Microsoft puts in their pages.  Firefox and IE won't show the tag when you view source.  When you inspect the page in Firefox, it won't show.  When you use the developer toolbar in IE, it shows the item but clearly scripts are not permitted to access it.  
When I attempt to use document.getElementById('Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem-Large').style.display='none';, it says the item is null or not an object.  The CSS works because MS removes the id after displaying the page.  More IE proprietary stuff that only MS can use.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification.  Adding the hide() method to the object did not hide the item.  It still displays.